# how to set module style tag to spotlight area - joomla template T3V3 framwork

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

how can I set the style tag for module that inside a spotlight?

the spotlight loads the modules, like this

```
$this->spotlight ('spotlight-2', 'position-5, position-6, position-7, position-8')
```

how I can control that the modules inside this spotlight have the style "rounded"

if the module not in a spotlight, we can put the style like this

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="<?php $this->_p('position-5') ?>"  style="rounded"/>
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get this to work , I did the following

I edited the **spotlight.php** file in **plugins/system/at3v3/t3v3base/tpls/blocks**

from this

```
$style = 'JAxhtml';
```

to this

```
$style = $vars['style'];
```

and then called the spotlight function inside my template like this

```
$info = array('style'=>'rounded');
  $this->spotlight ('spotlight-2', 'position-5, position-6, position-7, position-8',$info)
```

easy fix

I hope to see this option on T3V3 next release